# Illegal Cross Thread Operation error

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help needed for 'cross-thread operation error' in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606642/help-needed-for-cross-thread-operation-error-in-c-sharp)
>   [Solve a cross-threading Exception in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868783/solve-a-cross-threading-exception-in-winforms)

I've tried to add progressbar in the foreach-loop

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (...)
    {
        ...
        i++;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 * i / rcount);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    this.close();
}
```

now i have an Illegal Cross Thread Operation error in 
`this.close();`
 line

How can i solve it?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868783/solve-a-cross-threading-exception-in-winforms

Comment: There are hundreds, maybe even thousands of questions on SO about the same error. How many did you read before posting?

Answer (score 2):

Run the command in the ui thread:

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    this.close();
});
```

Comment: Possible but the Completed event is so much more appropriate.