# VB.NET Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: vb.net

I have a loop (BackgroundWorker) that is changing a PictureBox's Location very frequently, but I'm getting an error -

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'box1' accessed from a thread other than the
  thread it was created on.
```

I don't understand it at all, so I am hoping someone can help me with this situation.

Code:

```
  box1.Location = New Point(posx, posy)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Main UI windows not updating control -Cross-thread operation not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470390/main-ui-windows-not-updating-control-cross-thread-operation-not-valid)

Answer (score 3):

This exception is thrown when you try to access control from thread other than the thread it was created on.

To get past this, you need to use the `InvokeRequired` property for the control to see if it needs to be updated and to update the control you will need to use a delegate. i think you will need to do this in your backgroundWorker_DoWork method

```
Private Delegate Sub UpdatePictureBoxDelegate(Point p)

Dim del As New UpdatePictureBoxDelegate(AddressOf UpdatePictureBox)

Private Sub UpdatePictureBox(Point p)
    If pictureBoxVariable.InvokeRequired Then

        Dim del As New UpdatePictureBoxDelegate(AddressOf UpdatePictureBox)
        pictureBoxVariable.Invoke(del, New Object() {p})
    Else
        ' this is UI thread     
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For other people which coming across this error:

Try the dispatcher object: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

My code:

```
Private _dispatcher As Dispatcher

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
End Sub

Private Sub otherFunction()
    ' Place where you want to make the cross thread call
   _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() ThreadSafe())
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadSafe()
    ' here you can make the required calls
End Sub
```