# vb.net accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, text, label

I am trying to set text to label `Label_caller.Text = phone_number` and I get this error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Label_caller' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." How do I overcome this problem? How do I use keyword Me.?

Comment: pass Label_caller label as argument  to thread modifying its text

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET Cross-thread operation not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296564/vb-net-cross-thread-operation-not-valid)

Comment: This is probably THE most common question on StackOverflow.  Searching isn't that hard... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vb.net]+Cross-thread+operation+not+valid

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Windows, you can access UI elements only on the UI thread. For that reason, if you need to access them from another thread, you may need to invoke that action on the UI thread.

You need to use the following method to update the text box. This will check if invoking on the main thread is required and if needed, call the same method on the UI thread.

```
Private Sub UpdateTextBox(ByVal phone_number As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim args() As String = {phone_number}
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf UpdateTextBox), args)
        Return
    End IF
    Label_caller.Text = phone_number
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am probably answering quite late but adding following code in form load event seems solving problem.

Not sure though it's perfect answer or not:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Comment: That doesn't actually solve the problem, it just obfuscates it and makes it much, much worse...

Comment: @Taegost The question was "How do I overcome this problem?" not "How do I make safe, cross thread calls" so, this answer while it may not be the safest way to overcome the problem, is still a perfectly valid answer and does indeed overcome the problem and shouldn't be down-voted for that, especially since the same answer passed just fine on an identical C# post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38784153/6136296

Comment: @Shayna - This doesn't overcome the problem, it hides it.  It will likely cause the application to break in other ways, and more than likely, make that part of the code not work as expected.  This is a terrible practice that should never be taught to new programmers as a resolution to an error.